# Performing a health check in Kubernetes for a .NET 6 C# Console App that processes messages from an Azure Service Bus Message Queue

Tags: c#, .net, docker, kubernetes

I am trying to migrate a .NET 6 C# Console App that processes messages from an Azure Service Bus Message Queue to run in Kubernetes, instead of running it as a WebJob in an Azure Web App.
My desired target is an Azure Kubernetes Service, but I am currently attempting to test this out using Kubernetes through the latest version of Docker Desktop.

The application that I am using uses code from the "Receive messages from the queue" section of this Microsoft guide:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues?tabs=passwordless](https://stackoverflow.com)

The code that I am using runs with no errors as a WebJob.
The code runs with no errors in Docker Desktop as a container using a Dockerfile and Docker Compose file to run it using the latest version Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise edition as a Linux container (I’ve also tried Windows).

However, when I try to run this as a Service or Pod or deployment in Kubernetes through Docker Desktop, the pod is never ready and the outcome is always a crash loop backoff.
I am following this Kubernetes guide on how to perform a health check from the "Define a liveness command" of the "Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes" documentation located here:
[https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#:~:text=To%20perform%20a%20probe%2C%20the,the%20container%20and%20restarts%20it.](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have tried to search for the executable image file or another file that is in the build directory of the application.

Here are two examples of yaml files that I have ran in Kubernetes using the “kubectl apply -f ” command, which is where the probes are setup:

(from my liveness.yaml file)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: preprocessingvalidationservice6:dev
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - appsettings.json
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 5
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - appsettings.json
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      periodSeconds: 5
    startupProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - cat
        - appsettings.json
      initialDelaySeconds: 30
      failureThreshold: 30
      periodSeconds: 10
```

(from my preprocessingvalidationservice6.yaml file)

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: preprocessingvalidationservice6
  labels:
    app: preprocessingvalidationservice6
spec:
  selector:
    app: preprocessingvalidationservice6
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: http    
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: preprocessingvalidationservice6
  labels:
    app: preprocessingvalidationservice6
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: preprocessingvalidationservice6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: preprocessingvalidationservice6
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: preprocessingvalidationservice6
        image: preprocessingvalidationservice6:dev
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "250m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "750m"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - cat
            - appsettings.json
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - cat
            - appsettings.json
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          periodSeconds: 60
        imagePullPolicy: Never
```

The image policy is set to Never so that the image is pulled from my local machine.
Although I included the PORTS section as required for Service setup, no ports are used in the application.

I am unable to execute a directory listing (ls -al) in the pod through Kubernetes, which I guess is because the pod is never ready? However, I can see logs for the pod by setting up a local kubernetes-dashboard.

I have been trying this in various ways on and off for a few weeks now, and I have read many, many web pages found through various Google searches on the topic.
I have been expecting the application to run in Kubernetes, especially with the file presence health check.

Any insight into what I am doing wrong or how I should proceed instead would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you see any error messages in kubernetes pod logs?

Comment: No I do not see any error messages in the kubernetes pod logs.